# HTML column layout - automatically wrap div element to next column

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

I want an HTML layout with max 5 rows

If I have 6 items (i.e. divs) I want to wrap the 6th element in the 2nd column of 1st row
I tried the following, But can't get the 6th element in the next column.

[image]

```css
p {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color:gray;
}

.wrap {
 display: inline;
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div><p>I am bla</p></div>
 <div><p>Your mom</p></div>
 <div><p>Test</p></div>
 <div><p>Teddy</p></div>
 <div><p>James</p></div>
 <div><p class="wrap">John Appleseed</p></div>
</div>
```

**Update:** the Problem is that the items needs to have a flexible width, see here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1771956/float_html2.png

Comment: Do you want it dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If ancient browser support is not an issue, you can make use of [css3 flexible box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

```css
#container{
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction:column;
    flex-direction:column;
    -webkit-align-content:flex-start;
    align-content:flex-start;
    -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    height:500px;
    background:hotpink;
}
#container div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    margin:5px;
 background-color:gray;
}

.wrap {
 display: inline;
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div><p>I am blah</p></div>
    <div><p>Your mom</p></div>
    <div><p>Test</p></div>
    <div><p>Teddy</p></div>
    <div><p>James</p></div>
    <div><p class="wrap">John Appleseed</p></div>
</div>
```

*this is not a complete solution, hopefully you can tweak it according to your needs*

More about css flex @ [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I had the column approach in mind too. But the width needs to be flexible. My example how it should look like was maybe too less. Here a more detailed example how the layout should look like: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1771956/float_html2.png

Answer (score 1):

Going back some years, the Html layout was often completely built with the table element, today most layouts are not.
However, you seem to want your layout built table-like (rows, columns...) so I would not hesitate to use a table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>row 1 column 1</td>
    <td>row 1 column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2 column 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 3 column 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 4 column 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 5 column 1</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```css
p {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color:gray;
}

.wrap {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color:red;
}
div {
    float:left;
}
.clr {
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div><p>I am bla</p></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
 <div><p>Your mom</p></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
 <div><p>Test</p></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
 <div><p>Teddy</p></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
 <div><p>James</p></div>
</div>
<div><p class="wrap">John Appleseed</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

I used some javascript and position absolute to calculate the layout

```
$(function () {
// Handler for .ready() called.
var rows = 5
var items = $("#container").children()
var firstDiv = $("#container").children().eq(0)
var height = firstDiv.height()
var margin_bottom = firstDiv.outerHeight(true) - firstDiv.innerHeight()
var margin_right = firstDiv.outerWidth(true) - firstDiv.innerWidth()
var row = 0
var index = 0

items.each(function () {

    var leftPos = 0
    if (index >= rows) {
        var siblingDiv = $("#container").children().eq(index-rows)
        if (index == 10) {
        }
        leftPos = siblingDiv.width() + siblingDiv.position().left + margin_right
    }
    var topPos = ((height + margin_bottom) * row)

    $(this).css('top', topPos + 'px')
    $(this).css('left', leftPos + 'px')
    row += 1
    index += 1
    if (row >= rows) {
        row = 0
    }
})
});


#container {
background-color:gray;
position:relative;
top: 10px;
left:0px;
height:500px;
}
.item {
background-color:green;
position:absolute;
height:50px;
top: 0px;
left:0px;
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/punchbuggy/78Uxb/3/)